# How to increase speed of Speech-to-text transcription in iOS App?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I used the [Scrumdinger](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/getting-started-with-scrumdinger) example from Apple to create a speech to text feature in my app. As you can see in the gif below, the text starts typing many seconds after I start talking:
[image: GIF of the slow behavior]

The speech to text functionality is super slow compared to speech to text on native apps like Notes, and users hate that experience. How can I improve the responsiveness? This is the code I use which might be related, I tried to change some of the values without any success though:

```
private static func prepareEngine() throws -> (AVAudioEngine, SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest) {
  let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
  
  let request = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
  request.shouldReportPartialResults = true
  
  // Configure the audio session for the app.
  let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
  try audioSession.setCategory(.record, mode: .measurement, options: .duckOthers)
  try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
  let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
  
  // Configure the microphone input.
  let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
  inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in
      request.append(buffer)
  }
  audioEngine.prepare()
  try audioEngine.start()
  
  return (audioEngine, request)
}
```

Additionally, You can download the TestFlight version on [this website](https://deafassistant.com) and view the source code for the entire app on [Github](https://github.com/saamerm/BeAware)

Comment: When you say "native apps like Notes," you're likely referring to a different technology. Do you mean "if the user presses the dictation button on the keyboard?" That doesn't use SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest. It uses the dictation system (which you can't launch programmatically). The dictation system is limited to ~1m of audio total, and lacks features, but is also dramatically faster. For more on the two systems, see https://tidbits.com/2020/08/31/how-ios-and-macos-dictation-can-learn-from-voice-controls-dictation/

Comment: I have not tried it, but you might have luck setting the `taskHint` to `.dictation`. But it's possible it's not fixable with the Speech framework. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognitionrequest/1649386-taskhint

Comment: @RobNapier I tried that, but it seems to have just made it slower :D

Comment: I also tried adding defaultTaskHint to my recognizer, and that didn't help either. Thanks for the recommendations! But yes, it seems like the "dictation" might be different compared to speech recognition. And dictation is probably hidden behind private APIs

Comment: It is. I found Voice Control on Mac to be very hard to use for dictation, for just the reason you describe. It takes several seconds and then you get a big block. Another thing you might try is `requiresOnDeviceRecognition`. It's possible it's sending some things to the network. (Again, haven't tried this, my voice processing work has mostly been voice activity detection, not speech to text.)

Comment: Yup, just tried that too for both the recognizer and request! And also set shouldReportPartialResults to true. No performance improvement. Thank you for your help
Do you think its worth using my Apple Technical Support Ticket for this?

Comment: Definitely a good idea. Tickets expire and are quite cheap for what they offer, so when you hit this kind of a wall, that's a great time to use them (and I'm as bad as many about forgetting that :D)

Answer (score 7):

Find the `DispatchQueue` function call, try changing the `qos` parameter from `.background` to `.userInteractive` Sample code is wrong, has been reported to Apple.

Comment: Completely fixed the issue with very high latency on speech recognition results, thank you.

Comment: What's a `qos` parameter that you mention?

Comment: @Saamer the qos parameter referenced here is in another part of the sample code provided by Apple. that sample creates a dispatch queue for processing audio and sets its `qos`(short for quality of service) to `background`. There are some predefined qos values, each referring to how important this queue is to the app. by changing it to `.userInteractive`it gets a much higher priority